# Javascript arrow function instead of for...of

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

how can I shorten for...of syntax using arrow functions?

```
            this.id = 1;                
            let products: Product[] = [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Bycicle"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "iPhoneX"
                }
            ];


        for (let p of products) {
            if (p.id == this.id) {
                this.product = p;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Can last block be written in one-liner? I tried this but it looks so wrong:

```
this.product = products.filter(p => p.id == this.id)[0];
```

I'm looking for something like .FirstOrDefault in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`Array#find`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
this.product = products.find(p => p.id === this.id)
```

To get a equivalent to `firstOrDefault`, you could short circuit the result

```
this.product = products.find(p => p.id === this.id) || {}
```

Comment: It is OK, but I forgot to tell that I use TypeScript (because of Angular2), so I get an error in your second answer when I use   || {}  "Type {} is not assignable to type Product..."

Answer (score 1):

**[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** should do

```
this.product = products.find(p => p.id === this.id);
```

**DEMO**

```js
let id =1;
var products = [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Bycicle"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "iPhoneX"
                }
            ];
            
let product = products.find(p => p.id === id);
console.log(product);
```